# QuestDB stopped writing data because of the lack of the disk space, how to recover?

Tags: questdb

I had QuestDB v 7.3.4 working for quite a while but at one point the data took up all the disk space and QuestDB stopped.

I have added more disk space and expanded the file system. I see QuestDB ingests the data in the logs

```
2023-11-15T14:06:31.593232 I i.q.c.w.WalWriter committed data block [wal=trades_rt~5/wal13388/0, seqTxn=11791443, rowLo=121215, roHi=121268, minTimestamp=2023-11-15T14:06:31.593232Z, maxTimestamp=2023-11-15T14:06:32.099287Z]
```

But this comes back empty

```
select * from trades where timestamp >= '2023-11-15T14:06:31.593232'
```

How can I restore QuestDB writing after out-of-disk failure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QuestDB can suspend WAL tables if there is a write error which usually what happens when the disk is full. You can check if the table has suspended status using the query

```
select * from was_tables() where name = 'your_table_name'
```

To unsuspend, use SQL

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_name RESUME WAL
```

This will trigger an attempt to write to the table. If the disk space problem is resolved the writing should continue as normal.

Comment: hmm, tried and it worked, thanks!